# New gradle is downloaded but not really works

Tags: android, gradle

After I got this error while compiling my library of volley

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Could not open local class set analysis write cache (C:\Users\Vaibhav\AndroidStudioProjects\Volley.gradle\3.3\tasks_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localClassSetAnalysis). Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

I deleted the .gradle folder in my user directory as told by other users But when I restart Android Studio a popup appears saying Downloading .gradle 3.3-all.zip.It downloads the whole and takes approx 15 minutes to do it and takes approx 170 mb to do it.But in the end,I get a warning saying

> Error:C:\Users\Vaibhav.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9oh‌​c3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Edit the `gradle.properties` file to download a different version of Gradle. And you can use `bin.zip` instead of `all.zip` version to reduce download size

Answer (score 0):

The 3.3 version of gradle is causing trouble to many users; update to 3.5

File->Project Structure->Project

set Gradle Version to 3.5, Android Plugin Version to 2.3.2 and click Ok